# How to express $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2} + x\right)$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Express $$\cos \Bigg(\frac{3\pi}{2} + x\Bigg)$$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

My try:

$$\cos \Big(\frac{3\pi}{2} + x\Big)=\cos \frac{3\pi}{2} \cos x-\sin \frac{3\pi}{2} \sin x=0-(-1)\sin x=\sin x$$

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes! you are right!

Comment: Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

Recall the identities for sine and cosine in the four quadrants. One of the QIV identities is the following.
$$\cos\big(\frac{3\pi}{2}+x\big) = \sin x$$

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: No problem. By the way, your way was completely right. However, knowing the Quadrant Identities could help a lot, since you wouldn’t have to calculate $\sin (a\pm b)$ or $\cos (a\pm b)$.